# C++/C Shareing global variable between 2 projects in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, variables, global, projects

In VS, I have a sln including 2 projects:

**Project A:**

**A.h**

```
#include <string>
extern bool flag;
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
bool flag = false;

void funcA()
{
  int i = 0;
}
```

**Project B:**

**B.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "B.h"
#include "..\ProjectA\A.h"

void main()
{
    int j = 10;
    flag  = true;
    std::cout << j << "\n" << flag ;
}
```

I set projectA as DLL, projectB as EXE.

In linking, I get the error:  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "bool flag" (?flag@@3_NA)

Should I manually specify projectB to projectA in setting?

Thank you.

Comment: This is bad practce.  Have the DLL expose a get/set method to access the value.

Comment: @Loki: There is no application boundary here, the project A is a DLL which be loaded into the memory space of the other.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: I too prefer to export only functions and not data, but this same problem will occur for functions.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Just need to make it work. I know globle variale like this is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

**A.h**

```
#ifndef LIBA_API
#define LIBA_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern LIBA_API bool flag;
```

**A.cpp**

```
#define LIBA_API __declspec(dllexport)
#include "A.h"
LIBA_API bool flag = false;

void funcA()
{
  int i = 0;
}
```

(no changes needed to `B.h` or `B.cpp`)

Comment: Got the error: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool flag" (__imp_?flag@@3_NA) d:\...\ProjectB\B.obj ProjectB

Comment: @yfeng: Project A will create an import library.  Project B needs that when building.  The Visual Studio "Add Reference... To Project" feature should be helpful in setting that up.

Comment: Thank you. for projectA, I set Linker-General-Output File to $(SolutionDir)LIB\$(TargetName)$(TargetExt). Then for projectB, set Linker-General-Additional Library Directories to $(SolutionDir)LIB. But has same error

Comment: @yfeng: Project B needs the actual file name listed under Inputs, not just the directory.  Can you imagine how slow it would be if the linker read all (100s) of libraries in the system library path?  Why are you messing with this.  Add a dependency between the projects with "Add Reference" like I said in my previous comment.

Comment: It works! Thank you! Previously I didn't figure out how to add reference to projectB. I thought including the dirctory is the way...From this link, I added reference[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235636.aspx). The reason I change the output directory is to gather all DLLs from multiple projects to one location. It's handy to me than being distributed in each project.